# How to make the facebook like button "post to page" popup appear above the button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I looked around the web and found some vague answers that this cannot be done, I just want to make sure before I trash this whole idea.

So after I click on the facebook like button a "popup" appears below the like button asking me to post to my page. How can I make this appear above the like button since my button is at the bottom of the page.

Thanks!